# Using regex in python to find a string

Tags: python, regex, mediawiki

I'm trying to find a substring of a string s, starting with `{{Infobox` and ending with `}}`. I tried doing this with a regular expression, but it doesn't get any results. I think the fault is in my regular expression, but since I'm quitte new to regex, I hope someone can help with this. String s is for example:

```
s = '{{blabla}}{{Infobox persoon Tweede Wereldoorlog| naam=Albert Speer| afbeelding=Albert Speer Neurenberg.JPG}}{{blabla}}'

result = re.search('(.*)\{\{Infobox (.*)\}\}(.*)', s)
if result:
    print(result.group(2))
```

Comment: Exactly what are you expecting as output?

Comment: I suggest you have a play with e.g. https://regex101.com/r/rB2bM0/1, and note that you should use raw (`r''`) strings with regex to avoid issues with backslashes.

Comment: The string from 'persoon..' to '...JPG', so everything that's in the 'Infobox'

Comment: I tried like re.search('{{Infobox.*?}}',s).group() , which giving me the result in py 2.6. But doing group at the time of match object will be right approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *lazy dot matching* since your delimiters are not one-symbol delimiters, and capture what you need into group 1:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\{\{Infobox\s*(.*?)}}')
test_str = "{{blabla}}{{Infobox persoon Tweede Wereldoorlog| naam=Albert Speer| afbeelding=Albert Speer Neurenberg.JPG}}{{blabla}}"
match = p.search(test_str)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/OWjgG9)

If you use a negated character class, any `{` or `}` inside the Infobox will prevent from matching the whole substring.

Also, since you do not seem to need the substrings before and after the substring you need, you do not need to match (or capture) them at all (thus, I removed them).

Comment: Mind that in case you have a newline in your Infobox, you will need to use `re.S`/`re.DOTALL` modifier: [`p = re.compile(r'\{\{Infobox\s*(.*?)}}', re.S)`](https://ideone.com/cpm54O).

Comment: In practice this won't work terribly well since the infobox can (and often does) contain other templates. Parsing tree structures with regex is generally a bad idea ([the `{{center}}` cannot hold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) etc). Use something like [mwparserfromhell](http://mwparserfromhell.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

**Code:**

```
import re
s = '{{blabla}}{{Infobox persoon Tweede Wereldoorlog| naam=Albert Speer| afbeelding=Albert Speer Neurenberg.JPG}}{{blabla}}'

result = re.search(r'(.*){{Infobox ([^}]*?)}}(.*)', s)
if result:
    print(result.group(2))
```

**Output:**

```
persoon Tweede Wereldoorlog| naam=Albert Speer| afbeelding=Albert Speer Neurenberg.JPG
```

**NOTE**: The above regex will match till it meets the first `}` after `{{Infobox`.

**Important note:**

This will only work for the cases like the given sample input

It will not work if the input has a `}` in between `i.e){{blabla}}{{Infobox persoon Tweede Wereldoorlog| naam=Albert Speer| }afbeelding=Albert Speer Neurenberg.JPG}}{{blabla}}` **For cases like that stribizhev's answer is the best solution**

Comment: @maxmijn happy to help

Comment: The **the above regex will match till it meets  }}** statement is wrong. If you think `[^}}]` matches 2 characters other than `}` you are mistaken. It only matches **one** non-`}`. So, if the path contains `}`, this regex will fail. Actually, there are 2 ways here: 1) a tempered greedy token, 2) lazy dot matching. The latter is more efficient, and my suggestion is based on that.

Comment: @stribizhev agreed removing my answer

Comment: No why removing? You can provide an alternative with a tempered greedy token that will be just a bit inefficient.

Comment: @stribizhev I don't what to pollute SO with wrong answer :) and I dont know that much about regex to rewrite by regex

Comment: I edited your answer so that the description is in line with the code (and trimmed the regex a bit).

Comment: @stribizhev then to it will not match this case `s = '{{blabla}}{{Infobox persoon Tweede Wereldoorlog| naam=Albert Speer| }afbeelding=Albert Speer Neurenberg.JPG}}{{blabla}}'` with a `}` in between where as your answer does match that case

Comment: @VigneshKalai: Correct. That is what I was driving at from the beginning.

Comment: @stribizhev agreed :) so I will just state that this will only work for this case and will not work for cases with `}` in between and by the way I can't compete with regex masters

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '{{blabla}}{{Infobox persoon Tweede Wereldoorlog| naam=Albert Speer| afbeelding=Albert Speer Neurenberg.JPG}}{{blabla}}'

# start with Infobox and two chars before, grab everything but '}', followed by two chars
mo = re.search(r'(..Infobox[^}]*..)',s)


print(mo.group(1))


# {{Infobox persoon Tweede Wereldoorlog| naam=Albert Speer| afbeelding=Albert Speer Neurenberg.JPG}}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @stribizhev it shows a different approach, in that way is answers the  question.

Comment: I meant to say your code output is not the one that OP expects. The approach you are using is basically the same as Vignesh's.